# Is there a way to return boolean from relational in Sympy?

Tags: python, boolean, sympy

Code example:

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u
>>> 10*u.cm > 20*u.mm
10*centimeter > 20*milimeter
```

However, I want to return a **boolean**.

Comment: If there is, it would have to be implemented by the `units` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier solution to just use a package called [pint](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint). This package was created especially for manipulation of physics units.

```
>>> from pint import UnitRegistry
>>> ureg = UnitRegistry()
>>> 10*ureg.cm > 10*ureg.mm
True
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.